# Row with invisible cells

Tags: tables, formatting

Is there any easy way to obtain something like this in LaTeX?

[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/574631tab.png]

My guess was to try to make the first and third cell of the first row invisible, but then I lose the right and left border of the `Main 1` cell... I didn't find any package that would allow to do this easily, so if you have any package name or trick (maybe it's fairly simple using standard LaTeX tables, I don't know), it would greatly help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need of additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{5}{|c}|}
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Main 1} \\
\hline
Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4 & Title 5 \\
\hline
& & & & \\
\hline
& & & & \\
\hline
& & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first row could have been written also in the following way (so as to have the complete number of declared columns):

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Main 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \
```

If you want to improve the quality of your table, then the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package could be of interest (vertical rules won't now be allowed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c*{3}{c}c@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Main 1} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 & Title 4 & Title 5 \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(l){5-5}
& & & & \\
\midrule
& & & & \\
\midrule
& & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the table contents, even some or all of the `\midrule`s could be suppressed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "cleaner" to add another `& \multicolumn{1}{c}{}` for the first row? So: ``\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Main 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\``

Comment: @doncherry if it were absolutely necessary, yes, but in this case there's really no need to add it.

Comment: Well, it seems to work fine without it, but in terms of semantic completeness, it just feels wrong to me to have one row with only four rows, technically.

Comment: @doncherry I know what you mean; I'll add a note then.